# How to create and open a json file?

Tags: python, json

Does anybody know why this code doesnt work? We are trying to create a json file and write some information in it. The aim is to create a user account, save the password and name in a json file and then login and go on with other functions. See the code below. Any help appreciated!!

```py
player_data_file = 'player_portfolio.json'
with open(player_data_file, 'r') as f:
    if os.stat(player_data_file).st_size == 0:
        data = {}
    else:
        data = json.load(f)
    data.update({player_name: {"balance": balance, "portfolio": {}}})
with open(player_data_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: It seems to work fine when I run it. I created an empty .json file, put in a `player_name` of `"bob"` and a balance of `100`, and the data was written to the .json file as expected. So, you need to be clearer about what `this code doesn't work` means. Also this is not a [mre], as I had to define `player_name` and `balance` above. So, it's possible that the issue has something to do with how either of those variables is defined, but I think it's unlikely.

Comment: I don't find where ´player_name´ is defined

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the code "doesn't work"?  Do you get an error?